# Conditional in Text property

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have the following XAML which displays the value of a slider element with seconds after it:

```
<Run Text="{Binding ElementName=TimeToGetReadySlider,Path=Value}"/>
<Run Text=" seconds"/>
```

I want to have the second element be "second" when the value of the `TimeToGetReadySlider` is 1. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Are you wanting xaml only? If so are you open to using the [Behaviors Managed API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn458350.aspx) so you can just slap a quick DataTrigger in there? Personally I'd just label it "second(s)" and move on but I mean it's of course do-able.

Comment: Yes I am okay with that. It does not seem like something that should be so difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Converter for doing it. Try this implementation

```
   <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Slider x:Name="TimeToGetReadySlider" Maximum="10" SmallChange="1"></Slider>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=TimeToGetReadySlider,Path=Value,Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"></TextBlock>
   </StackPanel>
```

Here is the sample converter class

```
 public class ConverterClass : IValueConverter
    {      
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
        var val = (double)value;

        if (val < 2)
        {
            return val + " second";
        }
        return val + "seconds";
      }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
   }
```

Register it on your page

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <test:ConverterClass x:Name="MyConverter"/>
 </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I register this in WP-8.1? Which file and what xaml?

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers You have to register the'Converter' under App or Page Resources. Check last step.

Comment: Thank you. I believe that's the WP-8 syntax. Not WP-8.1. I ask this because I am unable to include it in WP-8.1. What I tried is something like this: `<Page xmlns:util="MyConverter"><Page.Resources> <util:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/></Page>  </Page.Resources>`. Then the output was something like: "no type `MyConverter` could be found in namespace `MyConverter`". Or does including your xaml code (`<phone>...`) in app.xaml work?

Comment: You have to give the correct path where your  'MyConverter.cs' file is placed @ErwinRooijakkers like  xmlns:test="clr-namespace:test" in silverlight where test is my project name & I added it directly in the project